# Sharing googleplus using UIWebView

Tags: ios, google-plus, sharing

I use https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/   to  sharing url-link  to the wall of Google plus.    For authorization Google+ Platform for iOS  using Safari.  How i can use UiWebView?

Comment: Did you find your problem solved ? I am also having same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, the oauth dialogue always links out to Safari, there is no way of running the auth dialogue via a UIWebView. Do file that request with the platform issues list though if you'd like to see that in the future: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list

Comment: I have updated latest google plus api. Still is there a no way of running the auth dialogue via a UIWebView? I am also having this problem.

Comment: Yep. We don't really want to encourage running it in a UIWebView too much, as it is very hard for the user to verify they are logging in to Google - and they will definitely have to enter their details, as the web view wont have any cookies.